# Angular 15 BrowserAnimationsModule breaks Google Docs Add-on: "Unexpected token '='"

Tags: angular, google-apps-script, angular-material

I am building a google docs add-on using Angular 15, using Gulp.js with gulp-inline to bundle all of the code inside an index.html file. The app works perfectly when deployed to the apps script platform, however, if I import `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` into my `app.module.ts` file, the app doesn't even open on Google docs, and it throws the following error in the apps script console:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='`

That's the whole error message. Apps script is a nightmare for debugging.

There's nothing special to the code, the most basic Angular app, fresh from `ng new`, will work perfectly without the module, and will break with the same error if the module is imported. `runtimeVersion` is set to V8 in the apps script manifest.

using `provideAnimations()` on the `main.ts` file yields the same result.

Any solution to this? I want to use angular material, and it requires the animations module to be included.